# Elementary probability problem - Evidence and Hypothesis

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is a second year undergraduate probability theory problem. I can prove the statement but cannot understand it intuitively...

A student is waiting for his exam result of some course. He does not want to hear any bad news. So he asks a friend to check on his behalf. His friend will flip a fair coin. If the coin heads up, then the friend will call him if he passes and will not call if he fails. If the coin tails up, then the friend will not call.

Let $\alpha$ be the probability that the student fails the course and $\beta$ be the conditional probability that he fails given that his friend does not call him.

Please explain intuitively why $\alpha \leq \beta$?

I can prove this by using Bayesian formula, but I cannot see the intuition behind... Thanks for help!

---

From the suggested solution: The hypothesis is that the student fails the course and the evidence is that the friend doesn't call. If the student fails, he will not receive a call. If the student passes, then he will receive a call if the coin shows a head. So the evidence supports the hypothesis. Consequently $\alpha\leq \beta$.

I cannot understand the suggested solution... I mean, for the case that the student will not receive a call if he passes the course and the coin tails up, we don't have an explanation. I don't know. Just quite confused. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I find the suggested solution to be poorly phrased and not very insightful.  I think it is much clearer to think of the situation as corresponding to a table, like this:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Pass} & \text{Fail} \\
\hline
\text{Heads} & \text{Call} & \color{red}{\text{No Call}} \\
\hline
\text{Tails} & \text{No Call} & \color{red}{\text{No Call}} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The event where the student has failed are the two red "No Call" outcomes, which we are told has probability $\alpha$.  That is to say, it counts the two red "No Call" outcomes in the numerator, and all **four** "Call"/"No Call" outcomes in the denominator.

But the event where the student has failed **given** that the friend does not call, excludes the one case where the student has passed and the friend flipped heads.  So while the probability $\beta$ of this result corresponds to counting the same numerator (the two red "No Call" outcomes), the denominator only includes the **three** "No Call" outcomes.  Since the numerator of $\beta$ remains the same but the denominator is smaller than for $\alpha$, it must be larger **except** when the probability of calling is zero--i.e., the student has no chance of passing, or the friend's coin always shows tails, in which case $\beta = \alpha$.  So we must always have $\beta \ge \alpha$.

Comment: To translate this answer more simply, every event that the information you're given excludes from your sample space is a "Pass" event, so the conditional probability of a Pass cannot have increased.